# How to type anything in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I want to be able to type anything in a JComboBox, even input that does not already exist in the dropdown. I need this because I need the drop-down suggestion feature. I have an api that provides me with some data(search results), when searching for a key word I need suggestions in a drop-down which I have managed with a custom model, but the JComboBox only lets me write input that already exists in the drop-down? How can I make it so the combobox allows all input?

Edit:

To clarify what I want my program to do: I type in some word in a search bar and click search. Through a connection to my api it searches if there are any matching results. If there are I want it to display those in a dropdown list. So it is not as if there are any fixed alternatives to choose from in the combobox, like color, country etc, but instead you search and then the alternatives pop up. Something like this without including too many details:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton search = new JButton("Search");
JComboBox list = new JComboBox();
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(list);
list.setEditable(true);
panel.add(search);
panel.add(list);

search.addActionListener(e->{
            //connects to api, reads input in searchbar, searches for the input in api
            ArrayList<String> name = //list of all matching results from api
            list.setModel(new ComboBoxModel(name));
        });
```

But this doesn't work because the combobox doesnt let me write whatever I want in the field, it only lets my write words that already are stored in the combobox, which in my case is none to begin with. I have made sure that the other parts (the model, api) work, so it is just that I want the text field to be "more editable".

Comment: That does not help. That method lets you edit the textfield, but only with text that is already in the drop-down, which is exactly my problem. My combobox is already set as editable.

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is an [auto-complete JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm).  It's hard to tell without your editing your question to include a [mre].

Comment: See my edited post. Does that still contain the dropdown feature?

Comment: Okay, why are the search results in a `JComboBox`?  What happens when a user selects one of the search results?  It seems to me like you need a separate `JTextField` and a non-editable `JComboBox`.

Comment: Because I wanted the dropdown feature which doesn't come with a `JTextField `, but using a separate `JTextField` and a non-editable `JComboBox` sounds like a good idea. I will try that!